# http.responseText is returning the name of the PHP function called

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using AJAX to call a function within PHP.  It returns my data fine but, it keeps putting the function name at the beginning of the returnText.

My Javascript/ajax

```
function getfirst() {
    var myphp=document.getElementById('myphp').value ;
    http=createRequestObject();
    url= tablename + '.php?filename=' + tablename;
    url= url + '&function=movefirst';
    url= url + '&seekindex=CustomerKey';
    url= url + '&maxdata=' + maxdata;
    http.open('GET',url,false);
    http.send(null);
    document.getElementById('myreturn').value;
}
```

MY PHP

```
<?php include '../../tophat.php';

$_REQUEST['function']();

function movefirst(){
    $filename=$_REQUEST['filename'];
    $seekindex=$_REQUEST['seekindex'];
    $maxdata=$_REQUEST['maxdata'];
    opendbdata();
    $query="SELECT * FROM ". $filename . " ORDER BY " . $seekindex; 
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $returnkey='';
    for ($i=0; $i<=$maxdata-1; $i++)  {
         $returnkey = $returnkey . mysql_result($result,0,$i) . "~";
    }
    echo $returnkey;
}
```

I'm looking up the first customer in my customer database it returns the record but at the beginning of the returnText is the name of the function.  Here is the beginning of the .returnText: `"movefirst4SEASONS1~4 Seasons Pottery~336 Hammond Dr NE~"`

I have never had this problem before.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Charmander, I'm not sure what your saying.  Please explain.

Comment: tophat.php checks it against a database of valid functions.  But that shouldn't casue the problem should it?

Comment: It must be something happening in tophat.php... Or double check that there isn't a chance that somehow the 4SEASONS1 in the database actually got a 'movefirst' appended to it.

Comment: That isn't it.  I created a new file "movefirst.php" included tophat.php in that one and called it directly.  It worked fine.  I also tried hardcoding my calls to functions and that didn't work.  I guess I will just make individual files for now.

Comment: Alos looking at the code, somewhere you have an "echo" of the function name. Just add "echo 1;", "echo 2" etc around tophat, and then different numbers inside the fucntion to see where "movefirst" gets added. Also check your javascript to see if your adding to output there.

Comment: Found it. echo $_REQUEST['function']; was in an include file tucked away.  I guess we can close this thread.

Comment: One last post.  I discovered that, when I deleted the last function in one of the include .php files.  I also deleted the ?> at the end of the file.  No error message but it was duplicating the return results.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you

- allow users to execute any functions that are available in this scope (something like `dropDatabase()` or `rebootServer()`) since you're invoking `$_REQUEST['function']`
- allow users to make any changes in your database or read secret information by taking advantage of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's some debug code left in tophat.php. Try placing a die() just after the include and see whether the new responseText holds ONLY the function name.

That said, I concur and upvote Steffen's answer -- a syntax like

```
$_REQUEST['function']();
```

looks like a disaster waiting to happen. Even if it is not, it still LOOKS like it is, which is bad anyway.